# Can an OK button do nothing?

Tags: buttons, modal-dialog

I guess the answer is probably "just be consistent" but if not I could use some fodder for arguments for and against.

**Here's the scenario**

1. A dialog box with a list of things to choose
2. Something needs to be chosen in order for the next screen to do something
3. If nothing is chosen nothing is done.
4. There is an OK and a Cancel button on the bottom of the box

[image]

If you select nothing and hit OK, should you get a box saying "Please select something" or just act as if nothing happened?

Comment: As several have mentioned, 'OK' is not a typical label for performing an action other than dismissing a modal. Since you are updating the state of the app here, I think 'save' or 'update' would be a much more meaningful label.

Comment: If this is the first time using the program, the user might have assumed that clicking OK without selecting would mean transfer everything listed in the box. So not doing anything might lead the user to think that the program is broken.

Comment: @DA01 I'd actually disagree, 'OK' is normally used as a final 'Apply + Close' type button... Think of the Windows Control Panel dialogs. 'Cancel' would be the one that doesn't do anything.

Comment: @RudiVisser that's what I had in mind when I asked this.  If you don't do anything on windows control panels, OK doesn't do anything.  Maybe I'm mixing metaphors.

Comment: @RudiVisser you are correct! Control panels do use 'OK' for state changing. So there is precedence. I don't agree with Windows on that, but that is a valid approach, I suppose.

Comment: so tempted to respond "well sure it CAN, but you may not want it to"

Comment: OK = Confirm. So if there is nothing to confirm, or it is unclear what you are actually confirming, then 'OK' would not be a good word to use. This is easily remedied by adding text somewhere (title of window, text in dialog...etc.) to is describing what you are confirming.

Comment: If there's a button and it's pressable, it needs to do something. Otherwise, don't make it pressable, or hide it.

Comment: I agree that "OK" is bad form in this case. I'd personally go with "Continue". I'd also grey it out until a selection is made. Not sure if a notification is required IMHO.

Comment: "You are now logged in" *clicks OK* seems like a fairly common use of an OK button on some sites where the OK is used for nothing but verification that they have indeed seen the message. Much like all these bars on sites informing about the use of cookies, you click ok, it does nothing but confirm you have seen it

Comment: @Sosukodo I am not sure that the default button *needs* to be the right-most one. That article is just someone's opinion, it's not a definite 'it must be done this way'.

Comment: @Sosukodo how about billions of lines of code?

Comment: It is always better to prevent error than display error message...so only enable the ok button whn i is possible rather explain the user he has something to do....he will  better learn and keep knowledge because he will make an assosiation between his action, like a selection item, and the changing state of the ok button. And as it is written give a better label....if is "save" for example the user will ask himself "why I can't save"....it is better for training and knowledge than the question "why it is no ok"

Answer (score 122):

In this specific case I would **disable the "OK" button, if nothing is selected**, then it's more clear that you can't do "OK" until something is selected.

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea, we should do that everywhere in our program.  The real reason I even cared about this was because I like how Delphi handles modalresult. I don't even have to program an event handler for the OK button. (saves me 2 lines of code)

Comment: When I do this, I always also leave an indication on the form as to **why** "ok" is disabled.  Something along the lines of a red, bolded label just above the buttons saying *"Please select an item or items to <verb>"*

Comment: @PeterTurner Basing your UI-choices on LoC is pretty bad advise. Almost always put your users first, and they seldomly care how much LoC your project has.

Comment: Agree with @k0pernikus, specially if you are going to ask for advice on a "User Experience" forum (and this is not sarcasm of any kind).

Comment: I'd also change the label on the button from `OK` to `<verb>`

Answer (score 51):

I'm sure we can find a better button label than "Ok". What about telling the user what he or she's accomplishing?

Examples "Save", "Add", etc.

As per Samuel post, keeping the button de-activated until an option is selected would be a good practice too, unless adding a specific criteria is not mandatory.

Comment: I dunno, OK is pretty spot on.  But I guess "Select" would work.  Then I'd be hard pressed not to say "nothing selected"

Comment: +1 It sounds like the user is explicitly updating information. This is not what OK buttons are for. It definitely should likely be a SAVE button.

Comment: In that case, I agree that "Ok" is acceptable, but still not best!

Answer (score 8):

Clicking OK with out a selection will do something...Confuse your users.

There are a few things you can do:

- As suggested, disable "OK" until a selection is made.
- Also mentioned. Is "OK" meaningful enough? Can the action be described
  better?
- Frame the dialog box better: I don't know what "Transfer In Words" is. Can it be "Select a Transfer Item" or something more directorial?
- If it's just one selection, why have an extra click? Why not
  just let the selection close the dialog box?

My final position: An "OK" alone can do nothing (AKA close the box). if it's combined with a cancel, consider UX improvements to prevent it.

Comment: Regarding your 4th bullet point, is it really OK to only have the selection close the dialog box?  It's definitely not OK if you've got a multi select thing going on. (transfer in words has a very clear and specific meaning for our program, but you're right that's a good suggestion in general)

Comment: Definitely! Particularly if the dialog box is framed as the necessary action to perform. The cancel or "X" remains as a way to back out. Picture it like this: Step 1:You have ap rompt on screen 1 to "pick a transfer". Step 2: List of choices is offered in the pop up framed in a box that directs user to "Select a transfer". User clicks one, it goes to the next screen. User Clicks Cancel the box disappears. Efficient and understandable. One less click in this world! YAY

Answer (score 7):

Since the Okay button takes the user to the next screen, it is incorrectly named. It should be called Next (and a well-designed wizard also has a Back button on screens other than the first).

Okay generally means "complete the action implied by this dialog and dismiss it" which is not applicable here.

The proper way to handle incomplete input is to show, but disable the Next button whenever the form is in an incomplete state.  This is done by "greying out", or whatever is consistent with the UI conventions of the platform.

A well-designed screen of this type will have an event handler for every single keystroke event, and other events, so that it can update the button's state instantly.

For instance, if all that remains for completion is to fill in one mandatory field, and a character is typed into that field, the button should instantly become enabled. And if that character is erased, the button should instantly disable.

If you want to inform the user that he or she must complete the form before the Next button will activate (it's not necessarily obvious to everyone), the modern way is to provide a tooltip. If the pointer is hovered over the disabled Next button, a tooltip can pop up with the explanatory text.

Dialog boxes are annoying. Imagine if locked doors popped up dialog boxes instead of simply providing the feedback of not yielding to moderate force. *"Error! You cannot get into this car because it is locked. And, guess what, right now you cannot put in the key even if you have it because you first have to dismiss this modal dialog. That'll teach you to jiggle locked door handles!"*

Answer (score 3):

There's a technique known as "progressive disclosure" which states (very broadly) that users don't need to be shown what they can't yet act upon... in your case, that further actions aren't available until options are chosen.

Without knowing more, In this instance, you'd be best placed to offer your list with an instruction: "Please select x before continuing" etc - at which point you can reveal an 'ok' button --or-- make your 'ok' button clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot provided I would say a very important detail to provide the user is a little direction such as telling them to make a selection, given at the top of the dialog box. Without the direction it may take the user a couple seconds to figure out what they have to do. Which means if you disable the OK button the user may still try and click the button but without any feedback.

I don't think having the button enabled is a bad thing as long as you give the user some feedback, just like what we do for form validation, the submit button is always enabled and if you try to click the button without completing every task first we display an error asking the user to complete the task.

Answer (score 2):

**Doing nothing when nothing has been selected and the user has clicks OK does not seem like a good solution for the user.**

In the example provided there is no indication the user has to select anything. This combined with the fact that there is no feedback on the 'incorrect' usage of the OK button could cause problems.

As an improvement I would do the following:

- Add a title or sentence indicating what the user has to do / what is happening in this dialog: e.g. "Select items to transfer".

  - It is always good to inform users reduntantly about what they are doing: they might have accidentally clicked a link / button.
- Use a descriptive text instead of OK, so that users will now what the effect of the action is even without reading the title or sentence: e.g. "Transfer". This ensures the user will be less likely to be surprised (dissatisfied) with the outcome.
- Disable the Transfer button until the user has selected a minimum of one item. You cannot transfer nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to me like a description of [wizard](http://designinginterfaces.com/patterns/wizard/) behavior. If so, your interface should have buttons "Next" and "Back" (where appropriate) in place of the "OK" button, and the "Cancel" button should stay. Then it will make sense to enable the "Next" button if the user has selected entries from the table and the process can advance further, or to disable it in case of no selection. The "Cancel" button serves when the user wants to stop the process associated with this wizard.

Answer (score 2):

**Ok button must always do something.**

It really depends on content of second dialog and purpose of selected items.

Eg.: "Download these N items" or "Download this item" or "Select some items to continue" [disabled] would clarify meaning of that action.

If user should not be bothered too long with this action I would go with one word "Choose" or "Select". Anything longer should users autopilot stop for a second so he can read it.

In case this dialog is just a quick check before next step even "Ok" should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

No. It can't, because that's counter-intuitive. Why? Because there needs to be a reason for it to be present to begin with.

You have a Window Title, a list of sorts and a couple of buttons.

What you want is for the user to see that and select something in the list, then indicate that the selection process has been completed.

Here's what I would do:

1. Have only the title and the list visible. No buttons.
2. Change the title to "Choose [whatever]" (if they don't want to, they can always click the red 'X')
3. Once something is selected, display the "OK" button. Maybe rename it to "Continue" to indicate that the user is about to move on to the next step in the process.

Answer (score 0):

OK should always select something to process.

1. Have **OK** and **Close** buttons
2. First item should be highlighted by default
3. If user does not want to select anything, he clicks **Close** button
4. If user clicks **OK** button, whatever is highlighted is picked for processing

This makes it simple and clean

Comment: I would disagree with you here. If you're always having the first item highlighted by default and enabling the OK button then that means the user could very likely hit OK and have confirmed the 'default' item as their choice without actually having consciously chosen it. Yes, that might be clean and simple but I am not sure that's what the user actually wants.

Comment: If user is provided with OK button and he is clicking OK means that he is cautious of the fact that he is OK with the value that is highlighted. If not, he should/would click Close button.